# Different menu xmls for different screen sizes

Tags: android, menu

Is it possible to define different menus for different screen sizes? I've tried adding folders `res/menu-large` and `res/menu-xlarge`, but the menu xmls I place here have no effect on my xlarge tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, just an idea, but too long for a comment:

I don´t think that this is supported, it seems that this is not documented. But a possible idea is, to set booleans on different values. For example, you could set som res-values folder:

res/values-xlarge
res/values-large
res/values-sw600dp

and so on. In that values, You could declare a boolean:

```
    <resources>
<bool name="isXLarge">true</bool>
    </resources>
```

or

```
    <resources>
<bool name="isLarge">true</bool>
    </resources>
```

etc...

Then create different menu layouts which You could start if one of the values are true.

menu_large.xml
menu_xlarge.xml
menu_sw620dp.xml

And at createOptionsMenu:

```
    @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   boolean xlargeValue = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isXlarge);
   boolean largevalue = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isLarge);
   boolean tabletValue = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.sw620dp):

   if(xlargeValue==true){
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_xlarge, menu);
   }else if(largevalue==true){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_large, menu);
   }else if(tabletValue==true){
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sw620dp, menu);
    }

   return true;
  }
```

I have never tested it, because the generated menu looks good on all screen sizes if you set different drawables to the drawable folders.

Comment: Thanks! Not a very neat solution since requires Java code branching, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: yeah, I know. But sometimes we need neat solution if there is nothing supported what we want to do.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create different menu folders for different screen sizes, for example:

res/menu
res/menu-sw600dp
res/menu-sw720dp

etc..

Then put your menu files in corresponding folders and they will be picked up at runtime.